# How can I call the frame change function in my python gui approach?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, lambda, frame

I try to build up a GUI.
So i setup a tkinter window and only want to change the shown Frame.
As I plan, every of that Frames will have own Frames, Buttons and so on.

For the Structure I want to have everything in its own File.

So i have :

- main.py : only functioncalls
- mainwindow.py : create window and frame1
- start.py : frame2
- cam1.py : frame3

I start with showing frame 1 with a Button to Frame2.
From there i have a Button to Frame3 but here i get an Error for the function call:

```
buttonok = tk.Button(frame2, width=50, text = "Ok", command=lambda:show_frame(frame3), bd = 2, relief = "groove", overrelief = "sunken", font = helv36)
NameError: name 'show_frame' is not defined
```

Here is the Code:

mainwindow:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\pyproj\\project1\\version1')
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import ctypes
import time
import sys
import os

sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\pyproj\\project1\\Lib\\site-packages\\paho_mqtt-1.6.1-py3.10.egg')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\pyproj\\project1\\version1\\cam1')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\pyproj\\project1\\version1\\start')
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import socket
import platform

import cam1.cam1 as cam1
import start.start as start

from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def show_frame(frame):
    print('show')
    frame.tkraise()
    
def window():
    welcome = tk.Tk()
    welcome.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    welcome.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    #show the window "welcome"
    #window.state('zoomed')

    #user setup
    user = ctypes.windll.user32
    
    #font setup
    helv36 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight=tkFont.BOLD)
 
    #startwindow size
    window_width    = int(user.GetSystemMetrics(0) / 2) 
    window_height   = int(user.GetSystemMetrics(1) / 2)
    
    #startwindow position
    screen_center_x = 0
    screen_center_y = 0 
    
    #frame setup
    top_framex = (window_width/4)
    top_framey = int(window_height*(1/8))
    left_framex = int(top_framex*2)
    left_framey = int(window_height*(6/8))
    lower_framey = int(window_height*(1/8))
    
    #start sizes
    fontsize = str(int(window_height/10))
    intfontsize = int(window_height/10)
    buttonwidth = 50
    label_start_fontsize = int(int(fontsize)*0.75) 
    
    #Fensterposition festlegen
    welcome.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{screen_center_x}+{screen_center_y}')

    #window grid setup
    welcome.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    welcome.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    
    #framesetup
    def frame1(welcome):    
        frame1 = tk.Frame(welcome,bg="yellow")
        frame1.place(relheight = 1, relwidth = 1)
    
        #font setup
        helv36 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight=tkFont.BOLD)
    
        buttonok = tk.Button(frame1, width=50, text = "Ok", command=lambda:show_frame(frame2), bd = 2, relief = "groove", overrelief = "sunken", font = helv36)
        buttonok.place(relx = 0.5, rely =0.9, relheight = 0.1, relwidth = 0.1)
        return frame1
    
    
    frame1 = frame1(welcome)
    frame2 = start.frame2(welcome)
    frame3 = cam1.frame3(welcome)
    

    
    
    
    for frame in (frame1, frame2):
        frame.place(relheight = 1, relwidth = 1)
    
    show_frame(frame1)
    
    welcome.mainloop()
```

start:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import ctypes
import time
import sys
import os

sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\pyproj\\project1\\version1\\main')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\pyproj\\project1\\version1\\cam1')

import socket
import platform

import cam1.cam1 as cam1
import mainwindow as mainwindow

from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
         
def frame2(welcome):    
    frame2 = tk.Frame(welcome,bg="red")
    frame2.place(relheight = 1, relwidth = 1)
    
    #font setup
    helv36 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight=tkFont.BOLD)
    
    buttonok = tk.Button(frame2, width=50, text = "Ok", command=lambda:show_frame(frame3), bd = 2, relief = "groove", overrelief = "sunken", font = helv36)
    buttonok.place(relx = 0.5, rely =0.9, relheight = 0.1, relwidth = 0.1)
    return frame2
```

cam1:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import ctypes
import time
import sys
import os

sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\pyproj\\project1\\version1\\main')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\pyproj\\project1\\version1\\start')
import socket
import platform



from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import mainwindow as mainwindow
import start as start
  
def frame3(welcome):    
    frame3 = tk.Frame(welcome,bg="green")
    frame3.place(relheight = 1, relwidth = 1)
    
    #font setup
    helv36 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight=tkFont.BOLD)  
    
    buttonok = tk.Button(frame3, width=50, text = "Ok", command=lambda:show_frame(frame1), bd = 2, relief = "groove", overrelief = "sunken", font = helv36)
    buttonok.place(relx = 0.5, rely =0.9, relheight = 0.1, relwidth = 0.1)   
    return frame3
```

I hope I didnt post to much code, but i think its better to understand that way.

As I understand I can use lambda like: command=lambda:"function"("object")

So as long everything is imported it should work ?

I hope someone can help me with that.

Greetings
Chorum

Comment: `show_frame()` is a function inside `mainwindow` module, so it should be accessed by `mainwindow.show_frame(...)`.

Comment: I tried that and came to an other error:
In mainwindow i use : ` - frame1 = frame1(welcome)
     - frame2 = start.start.frame2(welcome)
     - frame3 = cam1.cam1.frame3(welcome) ` to define the frames. It works with frame1 and 2 but on frame3 i get: `  File "C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj\project1\version1\main\mainwindow.py", line 37, in show_frame
    frame.tkraise()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tkraise'`

So the function call works but i think the object "frame3" isnt working somehow...

Comment: Note that `frame1`, `frame2` and `frame3` are local variables inside `window()`, so they cannot be accessed outside that function basically.  Suggest to change them to attributes of `welcome` window, i.e. change all `frame1`, `frame2` and `frame3` to `welcome.frame1`, `welcome.frame2` and `welcome.frame3` correspondingly.  But it is better to refactor your code to use classes instead.

Comment: I found out the same and got it to work. I would like to use classes but I am not familiar with them. For this question you helped me out acw1668. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `import os`, to close current and opet new file code will be something like:

```
file = 'python3 main_menu.py' 
root.destroy()                
os.system(file)
```